# react native real-time chat

Tags: node.js, sockets, react-native

I am trying to develop a basic socket IO chat app using nodejs express server and react native. I am new to the these stacks so could not identify the proper functioning with the components. I followed the conventions as provided by the official socket IO documentation but could not find anything in particular related for react native. 
I also tried same functionality for web i.e. react js and some how it worked but could not achieve the results for react native.

Here is my code from main client side component:

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
          this.state = {
          text: '',
          messages : [],
       }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:3333');
        this.socket.on('RECEIVE_MSG', (msg) => this.addMessage(msg))
    }
    sendMessage = () => {
        this.socket.emit('EMIT_MSG', {
            text: this.state.text
        });

        this.setState({text: ''})
    }

    addMessage = (msg) => {
        console.log(msg, 'any incoming msgs data');
        this.setState({messages : [...this.state.messages, msg]});
        console.log(this.state.messages);
    }

    renderMessages = () => {
        return this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
            return (
                <Text key={index}>
                    {message}
                </Text>
            )
        })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput    placeholder="enter your msg"
          onChangeText={(text)=>this.setState({text})}/>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sendMessage}>
            <Text> send msg </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>

            <ScrollView>
                {this.renderMessages()}
            </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is my server code for the same with express and server imported:

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected: ' +   socket.id);


    socket.on('RECEIVE_MSG', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);

        io.emit('EMIT_MSG', msg);

    });
});
```

The problem persists that nothing shows up in the console. Whenever I press the send button, the text does not even change nor does it shows any error message in the console. Please help me fix it if I am following the proper convention or not?

Comment: To simplify the implementation of real-time messaging you could use [QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/), there is ReactNative support with [documentation](https://docs.quickblox.com/docs/react-native-quick-start) and [samples](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-react-native-samples). It is possible to start using it for free (plan Basic).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.sendMessage}>
```

The arrow function there does not invoke this.sendMessage. Change your code to

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.sendMessage}>
```

and you should see a result.

You're also using Scroll view incorrectly, it's not just a parent view. In order to render items, you have to set the correct [props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview). This includes the `renderItem` prop which requires a function to display the data and the `keyExtractor` function which requires a function provide an invisible key value to React to ensure that the rendered items are unique.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. It worked and starting to show text from my interface but nothing is still showing up in the console.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information about the Scroll view.

Comment: But changing ScrollView into View does not make my fucntionality work properly. I am still not able to connect my app with socket server properly. Console does not shows anything.

Comment: Are you able to see or make sure that the socket is working correctly? As in, is port 3333 on locaclhost actually open and able to send and receive data?

Comment: No. The application gets started but does not gets connected to the socket.io server hence nothing shows up in console screen. But if i try the same with local html file, the connection shows up

Comment: Sorry man, connecting to socket.io falls outside my domain of knowledge.